# Webdeploy using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Currently, we see some pretty random deployment times to our Azure App Service (p1v2 and p2v2) based in West Europe. Some times it takes 3 minutes and some times it takes multiple hours to deploy the same codebase. Sometimes I cancel the webdeploy after 1 hour and then restart it, and then it completes immediately.

**Background info**

We use deployment slots for our deployment.

We deploy around 9000 files.

We tried to scale the app service plan up, but nothing related to deployment changed.

We use the task "Azure App Service deploy" v. 4.* with the following settings:
 - deploy to slot or app service environment
 - deployment method: web deploy
 - take app ofline
 - remove additional files at destination
 - exclude files from the app_data folder
 - additional arguments: -usechecksum
 - rename locked files

We have tried both hosted vs2017 agents and our own private agents. Its the same result.

The only deployment method that seems to work all the time, is deleting and re-creating the deployment slot on every deployment. However, then the webploy takes up to 20 mins, which seems pretty high.

Can someone help me understand how webdeploy to Azure App services using Azure DevOps works? And how to reduce the time spent deploying? I would very much like some more stable deployments.

Comment: Does the issue still exist? Has this happened before? This could be the availability degradation of azure.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT This issue still exists and has happened multiple times before.

Comment: By viewing several cases with similar issues, it is generally caused by events.You can check through this [site](https://status.dev.azure.com/) Reference case: [issue1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/746099/azure-app-service-deploy-task-stuck-and-does-not-p.html),[issue2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/791464/azure-devops-web-app-deploy-very-slow.html)